# Null bytes in shellcode? Why does mov eax,1 machine code have bytes that are 00?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, shellcode, instruction-encoding

Going through the shellcode article on wikipedia, it gives an example as follows:

```
B8 01000000    MOV EAX,1          // Set the register EAX to 0x000000001
```

To make the above instruction null free, they've re-written it as follows:

```
33C0           XOR EAX,EAX        // Set the register EAX to 0x000000000
40             INC EAX            // Increase EAX to 0x00000001
```

Where is the null byte in the first instruction? How do the converted instructions not have a null byte?

Comment: See also [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132985) - saving space also often involves avoiding instructions that can only use a 32-bit immediate when you only have a small number.

Answer (score 1):

The null bytes are right after `B8 01` in the first instruction.
The second instruction uses the `xor` operation to zero out *eax* (any `x xor x = 0`) and then increment it by one to achieve the same result without `00`, the *null byte*.

Comment: so here, is 0x00 is treated as 1 byte or 00000000?

Comment: 0x00 is 1 byte == 8 bit. 0x00000000 are 4 bytes / 32 bit, which is the length of a register on 32 bit (sic) machines.

Answer (score 1):

**Where is the null byte in the first instruction?**

```
B8 01000000    MOV EAX,1          // Set the register EAX to 0x000000001
     ^^^^^^
     1 2 3
```

There are actualy 3 null bytes

**How do the converted instructions not have a null byte?**
Because

1. The opcodes for XOR and INC do not contain nullbytes (http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32-abc.html)
2. Are here used only taking registers as arguments

For the `MOV EAX, 1` instruction, the assembler has to write the opcode (`B8`), and 2 arguments, from which one is a 32 bit integer. Since 1 is a very small number, the remaining bits are padded with zeros, resulting in a null byte.

The `XOR` and `INC` instructions do not take integers in your code, and don't have to insert zero's.

## Update

I didn't notice the +r in the opcode for `MOV r32, imm32`.

Registers are encoded using 3 bits in x86, and eax is `000`. 
 `B8` is in binary `0b10111000`, at the end are 3 free bits.

```
0b10111000 + 0x000 = 0b10111000 = 0xB8
```

So `B8` encodes to `MOV EAX, imm32`.

What left is `0x01000000`, what 1 is in little endian.

Comment: So, since B8 is the opcode for mov, 01000000 comprises of the two arguments? Then if 01 is 1 argument and the rest 000000 are for padding purposes, where is the first argument? Shouldn't 1 be written as 00000001 instead of 01000000?

Comment: `01000000` encodes for both arguments, but I have no idea how, x86 instruction encoding is very complicated. I think it looks reversed because of endianes.

Comment: @Lennart actually the `0x01000000` only encodes the second argument. `0xb8` is the opcode for `move immediate 32-bit value into EAX`. But you're right on the endianness - 0x01000000 is the little-endian encoding of a 32-bit value of 1.

Comment: @Lennart Okay. I understood the B8 part. What is +r in the opcode? Despite the fact that i did x86 programming a few years ago, i'm a bit confused on endianness right now.

Comment: @user85030 +r means a register code, from 0 through 7, added to the value. (http://ref.x86asm.net/#column_po); Endiannes: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) Basicly the bytes are reversed